# Scrolling issue on Vaadin 21 and ApplicationLayout

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin21

I have a strange problem with the application layout and views which need to be scrolled:

If I create an application with the default App Layout, the drawer toggle is on the top and I add a VerticalLayout with fullsize as view everything is working as expected. But if the vertical content exceeded the height of the browser window (even if I put this content into a scroller), the whole view get scrolled and disappears behind the toggle until the height of the toggle is reached, than scrolling stops.
It seams that `setHeight(100, Unit.Percentage)` does not considers the height of the toggle.

Has someone a similiar problem?

**Edit**

Put the following code as a view into an AppLayout and open this on your mobile device e.g. iPhone and you will see the vertical scroller:

```
@Route(value = "application/test", layout = ApplicationLayout.class)
@PageTitle("Test")
@RolesAllowed({"ROLE_NEWSLETTER_ADMIN", "ROLE_ORGANIZATION_ADMIN"})
public class TestView extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver {

    private MenuBar menu;
    private Grid<Person> grid;
    private Label footerLabel;

    public TestView() {
        this.setSizeFull();

        menu = new MenuBar();
        menu.addItem("New");
        menu.addItem("Edit");
        menu.addItem("Delete");
        this.add(menu);

        grid = new Grid<>(Person.class);
        this.add(grid);
        this.expand(grid);
        
        footerLabel = new Label("Number of objetcs: #");
        this.add(footerLabel);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent beforeEnterEvent) {

    }
}
```

AppLayout:

```
public class ApplicationLayout extends AppLayout implements AfterNavigationObserver {

    private ApplicationService applicationService;
    private H1 headerTitle;

    public ApplicationLayout(ApplicationService applicationService) {
        this.applicationService = applicationService;

        createHeader();
        createDrawer();

        this.setPrimarySection(Section.DRAWER);
    }

    private void createHeader() {
        // Define the header
        HorizontalLayout header = new Header(new H1("Header"));
        addToNavbar(header);
    }
    
    private void createDrawer() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: @cfrick: Please see the modified posting

Answer (score 0):

> It seams that setHeight(100, Unit.Percentage) does not considers the height of the toggle.

Correct. The 100% is the size of the view port. So if you have e.g. the following

```
VerticalLayout vLayout = new VerticalLayout();
Button button = new Button();
button.setHeight(50, Unit.Pixels);
HorizontalLayout hLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
hLayout.setHeight(100, Unit.Percentage);
vLayout.add(button,hLayout);
```

This will produce something where vLayout height is more that viewport height and scroll bar emerges. Instead you should do.

```
VerticalLayout vLayout = new VerticalLayout();
Button button = new Button();
button.setHeight(50, Unit.Pixels);
HorizontalLayout hLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
hLayout.setHeight(200, Unit.Pixels);
vLayout.add(button,hLayout);
vLayout.expand(hLayout); // or vLayout.setFlexGrow(1.0d, hLayout);
```

Comment: Hi, this is working, if you have a nested layout, but in my sitaution you create a "view" which consists of a vertical layout and this is "put" into the ApplicationLayout. I have extended my post by exmaple code to reproduce the problem. Florian